# What is the difference between NSOperationQueue and NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the difference between `NSURLSession` and `NSOperationQueue`?
Can we do the same thing in `NSURLSession` as in `NSOperationQueue`?

Actually both are for using background tasks. So my doubt: what is the difference between these two and what are the advantages and disadvantages in `NSURLSession` and `NSOperationQueue`?

Comment: They both have the `NS` prefix.  Otherwise, there's not much connection between them.  If you can't understand the difference in usage, you need to learn a hell of a lot more.

Comment: guide me anybody detailed

Comment: What's the difference between a dog and a wheelbarrow? They are totally unrelated things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `NSOperationQueue` is a queue for arbitrary computing purposes (you can put any kind of work in one of those - for example image processing) and management of threads, `NSURLSession` offers an easy-to-use interface for URL connections (uploading data and downloading data).

So, with an `NSOperationQueue` you can do everything you can do with an `NSURLSession` because using a background queue to start a synchronous URL connection is (apart from the configuration overhead that `NSURLSession` is supposed to take care about for you) logically the same.

But, the reverse is not true; `NSURLSession` would not be useful for arbitrary networking (for example raw TCP) or any non-networking related tasks.

Overly abstract any simplyfied, you may want to see `NSURLSession` as a very specific operation queue, that only allows URL-related operations.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Will you explain briefly...

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different between `NSURLSession` and `NSOperationQueue`

`NSURLSession` :- this is used to call web service in background. All operation relented to webservice call can be managed in the NSURLSession

`NSOperationQueue` :- This is used to performer any task in background in different thread. You can perform any kind of task in background thread except (UI operation).  In Operation Queue you can make dependent task using dependency so that task perform in some sequence.